# Create a new JwtBearer for external requests

Tags: asp.net-core, abp

I'm currently working on ABP Framework version 7.0

In the host module, I'm setting the authentication as:

```
    private void ConfigureAuthentication(ServiceConfigurationContext context, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        context.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.Authority = configuration["AuthServer:Authority"];
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = Convert.ToBoolean(configuration["AuthServer:RequireHttpsMetadata"]);
                options.Audience = "MyProjectName";
            })
)}
}
```

So I can access it with Postman as:

[image: ![enter image description here]

So it is throwing the token correctly. But now I want to set a new JwtBearer, so I changed the `ConfigureAuthentication` method to:

```
 private void ConfigureAuthentication(ServiceConfigurationContext context, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        context.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.Authority = configuration["AuthServer:Authority"];
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = Convert.ToBoolean(configuration["AuthServer:RequireHttpsMetadata"]);
                options.Audience = "MyProjectName";
            }).AddJwtBearer("jwt2", options =>
            {
                options.Authority = configuration["AuthServer:Authority"];
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = Convert.ToBoolean(configuration["AuthServer:RequireHttpsMetadata"]);
                options.Audience = "MyProjectName";
                options.BackchannelHttpHandler = new HttpClientHandler
                {
                    ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = HttpClientHandler.DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificateValidator
                };
            });

        context.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("my_jwt2", policy =>
            {
                policy.RequireClaim("scope", "Visit").AddAuthenticationSchemes("jwt2");
            });
        });
    }
```

I do that to separate the accessible methods from external requests. Now I want to get that token, but I can not find the documentation to get a specific token name; well, I tried to do the same, but changing the scope to `Visit` as:

[image]

As you can see, this is throwing the following error:

> "error": "invalid_scope",
> "error_description": "The specified 'scope' is invalid.",
> "error_uri": "https://documentation.openiddict.com/errors/ID2052"

Could someone please take a look at the issue?

Comment: Which auth server you have used now? Identity server or else?

Comment: I though is OpenIddict because the error refers OpenIddict documentation, how can I know which one is used? @BrandoZhang

Comment: Yes, you are using OpenIddict.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have the related scope in your database, then you need to register the scope first in the code. You can configure the `OpenIddictServerBuilder` option as follows:

```cs
PreConfigure<OpenIddictServerBuilder>(builder =>
{
    builder.RegisterScopes("Visit");
});
```

I think, then your problem should be resolved.

Comment: I tried that, but now is throwing: Invalid request: "This client application is not allowed to use the specified scope.",